# Actual Visibility in WPF

Tags: wpf, visibility, visual-tree

In WPF an element can have a Visibility of "Visible", but not be actually visible on the screen because it's parent (or parent of parent) has Visibility of Collapsed.

I want to be able to know if a element is actually rendered on the screen, without having to traverse up the visual tree checking parents.

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure where you are intending to check this but you can use the [IsVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.isvisible.aspx) property.